# Как очистить теги в materialize css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize-css

Не могу реализовать массовое очистка тегов, точнее при нажатие на кнопку чтобы все теги в materialize css chips удалять массово, так не нашел пути

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
    $('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip({
      placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
      autocompleteOptions: {
          minLength: 5
        }
   });
    $('#clearTag').on('click', (e) => {
     alert('Clear tag')
     $('.chip.material-icons.close').onclick
    });
    $('div > i.close').on('click', (e) => {
     alert('Close')
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       <div class="chips chips-autocomplete" id='tags' name = 'tag'>          </div>
      <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id='clearTag'>Очистить теги</button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: возможно `$('.chips').empty()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
    $('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip({
      placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
      autocompleteOptions: {
          minLength: 5
        }
   });
    $('#clearTag').on('click', (e) => {
     $('.chip').remove();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       <div class="chips chips-autocomplete" id='tags' name = 'tag'>          </div>
      <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id='clearTag'>Очистить теги</button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```